# htaccess, rewrite for specific subdirectory but not others below it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a subdirectory `/categories/stories/` that I want to rewrite to `/books/` but I don't want to rewrite something like `/categories/stories/horror`. I'm doing the following but it has no effect:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^/categories/stories[/]?
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/categories/stories/+[/]?
RewriteRule ^(.*) /books/ [R=301,L]
```

The result being if a person goes to, for example, `http://bookstore.com/categories/stories` they go to `http://bookstore.com/books` but `http://bookstore.com/categories/stories/horror` there's not rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use anchors in your regex pattern:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/categories/stories/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /books/ [R=301,L]
```

Pattern `^/categories/stories/?$` will match `/categories/stories/` or `/categories/stories` but not `/categories/stories/anything`.

Also make sure to clear your browser cache or use a different browser for testing this change.

Comment: I've reset my cache and tried different browsers that haven't seen this site before but nothing is happening...

Comment: Keep this rule as your very first rule on htaccess. Also I hope 
/categories/stories/ is not a real directory.

Comment: It's just an example. the structure is the same though. I have it as the first thing after `RewriteEngine on` but no dice, still not reacting :/

Comment: oh sorry there was a mistake. I had used `${REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}`. Use my updated rule as the first rule after `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: That change didn't redirect the landing page and actually cased a 500 error when going to `.../anything`.

Comment: What URL didn't get redirected and which one caused 500? Can you check Apache `error.log` as well for the cause of 500. It could be due to some typo error also.

Comment: `/categories/stories/` didn't redirect to `/books/` and subdirectories of `/categories/stories/` caused a 500. I can't access the logs. Unfortunately, those are kept out of my reach.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess inside `/categories/stories/` ? You need to contact admins to get access to logs because this rule works fine on Apache.

Comment: Worked with a coworker and found this to be the solution: `RewriteRule ^categories/stories/?$ /books [R=301,L]` placed at the end of the other rewrite rules. Looks like you were on the right track or it was likely something on my end.

Comment: Yes `RewriteRule ^categories/stories/?$ /books [R=301,L]` would also work fine if this rule is placed in site root .htaccess.